# Open Apple Music on Apple TV with deeplink

Tags: tvos, apple-music

Is it possible to open Apple Music from within an app with a deeplink, like:

https://music.apple.com/us/album/all-in-my-head-flex-feat-fetty-wap/1087445205?i=1087445220&uo=4

I tested it. It opens Apple Music "main page", but not the song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only works with a subscription to Apple Music. More tabs become available in Apple Music and the the deeplink works.